# Setting userInteractionEnabled=true/false on the overlaySKScene has no effect

Tags: overlay, scenekit, setuserinteractionenabled

I have a SceneKit view like so:

```
mySCNKitView.scene = a SCNScene
mySCNKitView.overlaySKScene = a SKScene
```

Now if I set the `userInteractionEnabled` property on the `overlaySKScene`, it has no effect i.e. it is always enabled and so I can't disable user interaction for the `overlaySKScene`!?
All added child SKNode's to the `overlaySKScene` will still receive user interaction…

i.e. this has no effect, it is always enabled

```
mySCNKitView.overlaySKScene?.userInteractionEnabled = true / false
```

I don't know if it is supposed to be this way?
But it seems like this is how one should disable user interaction for the `overlaySKScene`…?

Answer (score 0):

Apple Developer Relations20-Jan-2016 08:20 PM

This issue behaves as intended based on the following:

This is the expected behavior of the “userInteractionEnabled” in SpriteKit (which differs from UIKit). You have to set userInteractionEnabled to false to every nodes (not only the SKScene node) otherwise any node with userInteractionEnabled=true will catch the event. Note that SKNode’s userInteractionEnabled defaults to NO (expect for SKScene).

We are now closing this bug report.

If you have questions about the resolution, or if this is still a critical issue for you, then please update your bug report with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever solve this? I was experiencing a similar problem and then finally got it to work with the following:

```
let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
let scene = SCNScene()
var spriteScene: OverlayScene!

self.spriteScene = OverlayScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
scnView.overlaySKScene = self.spriteScene
scnView.overlaySKScene?.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

With the above code, my entire overlay scene is ignored, events are received by the SceneKit scene as desired. This is in Xcode 7.3 beta, tvOS deployment target 9.1, so maybe it's something that Apple changed recently?

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try and see…and be back…

Comment: No this issue is still around in my game. Could you post your project for download so I can test it out?

Comment: I think that is because you may be targeting tvOS only. tvOS works differently...there is no touch/click surface. Did you try this on Mac OS X or iOS?